# Is that possible to add a side menu to a specific fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm developing an android app which implements master/detail flow. To switch between master/details them I'm using `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter` because it allows to slide views.

Is that possible to add a `NavigationDrawer` to a specific fragment in ViewPager (to the master view only in my case)? And how to do it?

Comment: what is a `side menu`? NavigationDrawer you mean? If yes, then you can at least add it to the host Activity, and show/hide it depending on current selected fragment in ViewPager

Comment: you should really use fragmentmanager instead of viewpager, with correct animations you can still slide in your detailfragment

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. You can do almost whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your host activity and then control the show/hide of the navigation drawer in viewpager change listener.